# Unable to scroll over text input Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hey guys I'm facing a problem in scroll over `TextInput` in `android`.
In iOS everything working fine and when I use `multiline={true}`
it takes extra new line when go to next line. 
How do I fix it? Here is my code:

```
<TextInput
    placeholder='last name'
    multiline={Platform.OS === 'ios'? false: true}
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
    scrollEnabled={Platform.OS === 'ios'? false: true}
    blurOnSubmit = {Platform.OS === 'ios'? true: false}
    numberOfLines={1}
    style={[styles.formwelcome,]}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({lastname: text})}
    autoGrow={ false }
    ref='lastname'
    returnKeyType='next'
    onSubmitEditing={(event) => {this.refs.address.focus();}}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add  `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` this property inside your `ScrollView`

So your `ScrollView` will look like

```
   <ScrollView
         keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
         .....
   </ScrollView>
```